# Remote Desktop in Linux like Team Viewer

Tags: linux

For Remote Desktop Sessions in Linux, I want to know if there something available equivalent for what Team Viewer does for windows?

The main advantage I find of Team viewer is that it can bypass firewalls, needs no NAT configurations or port forwarding rules to be setup in the router.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FreeNX

Comment: This should be moved to SuperUser

Comment: FreeNX, is it supported on RHEL 4.0 Linux version also?

@ Josh - What is SuperUser? Is it some some forum. If so please post a link of it.

Comment: The link to superuser.com is at the bottom of this very page, next to a blue square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Erm, TeamViewer is not only for Windows - besides full Mac implementation, it also has Linux support (although it's beta). I haven't tried, but... Did you?

Comment: Do you mean team viewer has native support for linux as in it has rpms etc. built for it? Or that it needs to be installed via WINE software?

Answer (score 2):

One of the [vnc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vnc) family?

You will have to make the computer visible to the client machine, if you don't want to mess around with firewalls you will need a third party reflector service to connect both of you.

The price of dog food being what it is, we should probably plug [copilot](https://www.copilot.com/), although there are probably a bunch of free ones.

Comment: For VNC Viewer you have to rely that certain ports are not blocked by the Admin. 
Which are the free ones that do the same as copilot?

Comment: VNC can work over port80, the difficulty is that the server must be visible to the client -eg. by port forwarding. The 3rd party reflectors allow both machines to make an outgoing connection and copilot links them together.  I don't know of the current best VNC reflectors they come and go.